# HTML Contact Form - PHP Query

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Please help me out. I want this script to highlight the required fields, if left empty. It's simply reloading the page instead of showing the error. As far as I know, the problem is with the header("Location: ht.... - this line.
Being new to the contact form part, I'm unable to solve.

```
<?php
    $filled = true;
    $required = array("cf_name", "cf_email", "cf_message"); //all the required fields

    foreach ($required as &$value) {

        if($_POST[$value]==""){
            $filled = false;
        }
    }

    if (!$filled){
        header("Location: http://www.ashishagrawal.me/#contact"); 
    }

    else{
        $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
        $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
        $field_message = $_POST["cf_message"];

        $mail_to = 'some@email.here'; //put your email
        $subject = 'Message from '.$field_name;

        $field_message="From: {$field_name}
        Email: {$field_email}
        Message: {$field_message}";

        $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

        $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $field_message, $headers);

        if ($mail_status) { 
            echo "
                <script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert('Thankyou! I will contact you shortly.');
                    window.location = 'index.html';
                </script>";    
        }

        else {
            echo "
                <script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to somemail@yahoo.com');
                    window.location = 'index.html';
                </script>";
        }
    }

?>
```

The HTML Code

```
        <h4>Drop Me a Message</h4>
    <form class="row-fluid" action="contact.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="span12" name="cf_name" placeholder="YOUR NAME*" /><br/> 
        <input type="text" class="span12" name="cf_email" placeholder="EMAIL*" /><br/>
        <textarea name="cf_message" class="span12" rows="5" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE*"></textarea><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-icon glyphicons envelope">
            <i></i> Send Message
        </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You'd probably want to validate the contact form using JavaScript via jQuery instead. That said, it's better if you add the contact form html so we could help you better.

Comment: Posting your email on [so] is an excellent way of getting spammed.

Comment: Hello there find My solution to your question. and use this as HTML code portion to solve your current problem.i here using HTML 5 form validation to check a field is `required` or not.And i think you must expecting this as your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Empty fields are often not sent by the browser at all. Use `empty()` or `isset()` to check if they are set.

Answer (score 0):

You just use this html code..i just adding "required" attributes in html5 to your input form fields to check whether input fields are set or not.

```
<form class="row-fluid" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="span12" name="cf_name" placeholder="YOUR NAME*" required="required" /><br/> 
    <input type="text" class="span12" name="cf_email" placeholder="EMAIL*" required="required" /><br/>
    <textarea name="cf_message" class="span12" rows="5" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE*" required="required"> </textarea><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-icon glyphicons envelope">
        <i></i> Send Message
    </button>
</form>
```

it can used for avoiding  empty checking in html form inputs using php too..